# Error in quantmod::Lag when adding columns to a dataframe

Tags: r, quantmod

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
tickers <- c('AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL')
returns <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, -0.15, -0.25, .09, 0.4, -0.2)

df <- data.frame(tickers, returns)

df
  tickers returns
1    AAPL    0.10
2    AAPL    0.20
3    AAPL    0.30
4    AAPL   -0.15
5    AAPL   -0.25
6    AAPL    0.09
7    AAPL    0.40
8    AAPL   -0.20
```

I would like to add a column with the lagged returns.  To do so, I use:

```
df$lag_1 <- Lag(df$returns , k=1)
```

Which produces:

```
  tickers returns Lag.1
1    AAPL    0.10    NA
2    AAPL    0.20  0.10
3    AAPL    0.30  0.20
4    AAPL   -0.15  0.30
5    AAPL   -0.25 -0.15
6    AAPL    0.09 -0.25
7    AAPL    0.40  0.09
8    AAPL   -0.20  0.40
```

So far, so good.  But, when I try to use a ***variable*** to define the 2-day lag, I get an error message:

```
lookup <- 'returns'

df$lag_2 <- Lag(paste('df$', lookup) , k=2)

Error in Lag.default(paste("df$", lookup), k = 2) : 
  x must be a time series or numeric vector
```

Comment: What is `Lag`? State package please.

Comment: It's part of the `stats` package, apologies.

Comment: No, the function in `stats` is `lag`, not `Lag`. I think in this context, `Lag` is from `quantmod`

Comment: Yes, I believe it is!  I import `quantmod` (and other packages) from `tidyverse` and `tidyquant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stats::lag` function is designed for application to time series objects. It is not designed to "lag" ordinary vectors. The lagging of a time series object is accomplished by altering its time base. The `quantmod` package's help page for its `Lag` function describes the differences succinctly:

> This function differs from `lag` by returning the original series modified, as opposed to simply changing the time series properties. It differs from the like named `Lag` in the Hmisc as it deals primarily with time-series like objects.

> It is important to realize that if there is no applicable method for `Lag`, the value returned will be from `lag` in base. That is, coerced to 'ts' if necessary, and subsequently shifted.

Neither the question, nor the current answer have included the needed code to load the `quantmod` package:

```
 library(quantmod)
```

The other learning opportunity is that the expression `paste('df$', lookup)` will never be effective. That attempt probably comes from experience with what are called "macro" languages". R does not parse and interpret constructed strings like that. The unquoted strings typed at the console are handled differently than strings built with `paste` or `paste0`. As @akrun demonstrated, it is possible to use the extraction and assignment operators, `[[` and `[[<-`, with string valued values.

And a third learning opportunity comes from noticing that the name that appears at the top of your new column was not the same on that you assigned to it. What happened is that the result from `quantmod::Lag` was a matrix named "Lag.1" rather than a vector. The quantmod package is designed to work with `zoo`-like objects which are matrices rather than dataframes. Noter further that trying to access that clumn with the name that appears in the `print`-representation will not succeed:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ tickers: chr  "AAPL" "AAPL" "AAPL" "AAPL" ...
 $ returns: num  0.1 0.2 0.3 -0.15 -0.25 0.09 0.4 -0.2
 $ lag_1  : num [1:8, 1] NA 0.1 0.2 0.3 -0.15 -0.25 0.09 0.4
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "Lag.1"
> df$Lag.1         # FAIL
NULL
> df$lag_1         # Success
     Lag.1
[1,]    NA
[2,]  0.10
[3,]  0.20
[4,]  0.30
[5,] -0.15
[6,] -0.25
[7,]  0.09
[8,]  0.40
```

If you will be using "quantmod" or "tidyquant", you will definitely need to understand he differences in accessing values inside matrices versus  accessing values in matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Use `[[` instead of `$`

```
library(quantmod)
df$lag_2 <- Lag(df[[lookup]], k = 2)[,1]
```

-output

```
> df
  tickers returns lag_2
1    AAPL    0.10    NA
2    AAPL    0.20    NA
3    AAPL    0.30  0.10
4    AAPL   -0.15  0.20
5    AAPL   -0.25  0.30
6    AAPL    0.09 -0.15
7    AAPL    0.40 -0.25
8    AAPL   -0.20  0.09
```

Comment: if I had a column named "returns_AAPL" and a variable named "sym" that held the value "AAPL", how might I add a column using something like this?  `df$lag_2 <- Lag(paste('returns_', sym), k=1)`

Comment: @equanimity that would be `Lag(df[[paste0('returns_', sym)]], k = 1)`

Comment: @equanimity your code missed the `data` part. Also by default `paste` create a space because `sep = " "`, instead use `paste0` which is `sep = ""`